# How to format a date in JS

Tags: javascript, date

I have created a simple javascript to add 5 days to the current date. I am now having issues getting it to display the format day, date month i.e. Tue 7th Nov. Please can someone help

```js
var newDt = new Date();
newDt.setDate(newDt.getDate() + 5);
document.writeln("" + newDt);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this. If you want it in the format of `Weekday Month Day Year` remove the `.slice(0, -5);` on `date`.

There is plenty of documentation online. You have to look.

Read more about `toDateString()` [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

Read more about `.slice()` [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp)

```js
var newDt = new Date();
newDt.setDate(newDt.getDate() + 5);
var date = newDt.toDateString();
document.writeln("" + date.slice(0, -5));
```

To make it in the format you want, `Weekday Day Month` use this example.

```js
var date = new Date();
var locale = "en-us";

var weekdayNumber = date.toLocaleString(locale, { weekday: "short"});
var calenderDay = date.getDate();

var month = date.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "short" });
document.writeln(weekdayNumber + " " + calenderDay + "th " + month);
```

Be careful with dates like the `1st` and `2nd` or anything other than `th`

Comment: That's great thanks. Still very new to JS. Just a quickie, how do I swap the month and date round and add a th, after the date? Can't see that on the links?

Comment: @HashtagCV Consider accepting my answer or others if it solved your problem, or upvote if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
newDt.toDateString()
```

will return "Tue Nov 12 2017"

Alternatively, you can use a variety of date methods to build a date string that might be more amenable to your needs.

See date methods here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp